# stream tweets from different locations

Tags: python, stream, tweepy

How can I stream tweets from a country using a box-boundaries rectangle?
I have code to stream by location but I want to do a loop that says: for each tweet see if this tweet is in rectangle 1 or rectangle2 or in rectangle(n) else do not take this tweet.

The code I have is:

```
     import sys
     import tweepy
     from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
     from tweepy import OAuthHandler
     from tweepy import Stream


     consumer_key = ''
     consumer_secret = ''
     access_token = ''
     access_token_secret=''


     auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
     auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
     api = tweepy.API(auth)

     class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
      def on_data(self, data):

                 print (data)
                 return True              

         def on_error(self, status):
         print (status)

    sapi = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener())    
    sapi.filter(locations=[1.9,34.7,7.94,36.63])
```

In this code I filter for one rectangle but I want a code like this:

```
For each tweet t_i:
    For each rectangle r_j:
        If tweet_is_in_rectangle(r_j) == False:
            exclude t_i
```

Comment: In your French pseudo code, what is FSI? Is that to close your if statement?

Comment: hi Scott, FSI is end if.